# Webkit keyframe not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-animations

Why is my keyframes animation (http://jsfiddle.net/ZcFre/) not working in Chrome?

My CSS is:

```
.circle1 {
    -webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. It's a recommended practice here to post the relevant code in the question, and don't rely exclusively on a link. Since this is your first post, I have done it for you. But you should read the FAQ !

Comment: I was going to but the UI to add the code is really silly (have to put in 4 spaces on each line) I don't have time to press space 4 times on each line. Maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but not the easy way. See here [http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139751/215241]

Answer (score 4):

You've put a semicolon after the last curly brace of your animation declaration. Firefox accepted it, but Chrome didn't.

After fixing it, your animation spins again: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcFre/1/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }; <--Remove the semicolon
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I must have missed those. Does Chrome has an error log where I can see this?

Comment: @user2537644 No, but you can use http://csslint.net/ to check whether your CSS is OK. It's also available as a commandline tool, and as a plugin for several IDEs/build scripts.